# Can i skip a test inside tesng.xml?

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a scenario where some of my test are failling in IE and Firefox but working on Chrome. So i was thinking is is possible inside testng.xml to skip the class that contains the test.

Example testng.xml

```
<suite  name="Test "   parallel="tests"   data-provider-thread-count="2">
 <listeners>
           <listener class-name="ww5.listener.Listener" />
 </listeners>  
 <test name=" Chrome" preserve-order="true" >
     <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
     <parameter name="URL" value="http://95" />
     <classes>
              <class name="ww5.testcases.storageRuleSuite.GoToStorageRulePageTest" ></class> 
              <class name="ww5.testcases.storageRuleSuite.CreateNewStorageRuleTest" ></class>     
     </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="IE" preserve-order="true">
     <parameter name="browser" value="internet explorer"/>
     <parameter name="URL" value="http://95" />
     <classes>
              <class name="ww5.testcases.storageRuleSuite.GoToStorageRulePageTest" ></class> 
              <class name="ww5.testcases.storageRuleSuite.CreateNewStorageRuleTest" ></class>    
     </classes>
 </test> 
  <test name="Firefox" preserve-order="true">
     <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
     <parameter name="URL" value="http://95" />
     <classes>
              <class name="ww5.testcases.storageRuleSuite.GoToStorageRulePageTest" ></class> 
              <class name="ww5.testcases.storageRuleSuite.CreateNewStorageRuleTest" ></class>    
     </classes>
 </test>
```

Can i specify somewhere inside the testng.xml, i want to skip the test

```
<class name="ww5.testcases.storageRuleSuite.CreateNewStorageRuleTest" ></class>
```

inside the firefox test.

Comment: What if you just simply comment that line? :)

Comment: @peetya I could but need to show the test is skipped or ignored in my reports.

Comment: If they are failing they should say failed in reports. Isnt it ?

Comment: @AhmedYaslem What do you mean by "skip the test"? Not running it or having it in the skipped tests list?

Comment: @juherr i mean having it in the skipped tests list.

Comment: @AhmedYaslem Check my answer. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IHookable](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#ihookable) listener.

```
public class MyHook implements IHookable {
  public void run(final IHookCallBack icb, ITestResult testResult) {
    ITestContext context = testResult.getTestContext();
    String browser = context.getAttribute("browser");
    if ("firefox".equals(browser) && <add your logic here>) {
      throw new SkipException("The method " + ... + " is not working with firefox");
    }
    icb.callback(testResult);
  }
}
```

Then, just [register the listener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-testng-xml) in your `testng.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the tests that are failing to a group:

```
@Test(groups = { "failures" })
```

Then inside `testng.xml` you add:

```
<test name="Firefox" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
    <parameter name="URL" value="http://95" />
    <groups>
        <run>
            <exclude name="failures"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="ww5.testcases.storageRuleSuite.GoToStorageRulePageTest" ></class>     
    </classes>
</test>
```

Then you can just add the group to whatever tests are currently failing.

Comment: The solution doesn't work as the goal is to have "failures" tests in the skipped tests list.